# How to perform multiple runs and save output data from anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I want to perform multiple runs without the simulation experiment( parameters variation) mode. And save the output data after each run. Can someone please explain to me how to do it? Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you require some bash scripting. So it that script you may run your program multiple times:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/your_program --param 1 > experiment_1.output.txt
/path/to/your_program --param 2 > experiment_2.output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. :)